# Chrome timeline does not have frame mode

Tags: google-chrome

My chrome devtool timeline does not have the frames mode showing below. How can I switch to the frames mode?[devtool window img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOUXp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The frames mode have been recently removed from DevTools. There's now a frame rate chart (green one) on the overview though.

Comment: Thank you. I think the frames mode is way better.